# Working on Google Bigquery. Not sure how to parameterize the below query or make it more clean

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, parameterized-query

This is my query. In it, the objective is to obtain cohort retention. The results are perfect but I want to improve the quality of the code.
Working on Google Bigquery. Not sure how to parameterize the below query or make it cleaner.

```
#standardSQL

Select  Date_trunc(X.first_order, week) as cohort, count(distinct Y.customerId) as G_0,

CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 1 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_1,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 2 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_2,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 3 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_3,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 4 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_4,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 5 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_5,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 6 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_6,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 7 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_7,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 8 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_8,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 9 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_9,
CAST((count(distinct case when date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 10 then Y.customerId END)*100/count(distinct Y.customerId)) as INT64) as G_10

from (Select customerId, Date(orderProcessingTime) as order_time from UserData.Table_1) as Y 

left join
(SELECT customerId, min(Date(orderProcessingTime)) as first_order FROM UserData.Table_1 group by 1) as X
on Y.customerId = X.customerId

group by 1
order by 1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to always separate shares and ratios from absolute values. I first create a table on which I want to perform my calculations and then do just that. It's also a bit more flexible when playing around with those shares/ratios.
For your case, it would look something like this - couldn't test it, but I think you see the point:

```
#standardSQL
-- create a table to work with:
WITH tabl AS (
  Select  
    Date_trunc(X.first_order, week) as cohort, 
    count(distinct Y.customerId) as G_0,
    count(distinct IF(date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 1, Y.customerId, NULL )) G_1_cust,
    count(distinct IF(date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 2, Y.customerId, NULL )) G_2_cust,
    count(distinct IF(date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 3, Y.customerId, NULL )) G_3_cust,
    count(distinct IF(date_diff(Y.order_time, X.first_order, week) = 4, Y.customerId, NULL )) G_4_cust
    -- etc

  from 
    (Select customerId, Date(orderProcessingTime) as order_time from UserData.Table_1) as Y 
  left join
    (SELECT customerId, min(Date(orderProcessingTime)) as first_order FROM UserData.Table_1 group by 1) as X
  on Y.customerId = X.customerId
  group by 1
)

-- work with that table
SELECT 
  cohort,
  DIV(G_1_cust * 100, G_0) AS G_1,
  DIV(G_2_cust * 100, G_0) AS G_2
  -- etc
FROM tabl
ORDER BY 1
```

Instead of casting I used integer division function `DIV()`.
And instead of case-when I used `IF()`

Hope it all makes sense

Comment: That definitely makes sense. Adding to the answer, can you also direct me if there is a possible way in which the part of the query where I have repeated the statement (I mean the G_0, G_1, G_2 etc.) can be written more gracefully? 
Something similar to a for loop?

Comment: There are no explicit loops in SQL. You need to write some sort of statement for every column you want to have. In your case, you couldn't even apply mathematical shortcuts because of counting uniques. For cases like these I'm simply using spreadsheets functions to glue my queries together. Something like `="COUNT(DISTINCT id"&ROW()&") AS G_"&ROW()&"_cust, "`

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to use window functions.

```
with t AS (
      Select date_trunc(t.min_order_date, week) as cohort, 
             count(distinct t.customerId) as G_0,
             count(distinct case when datediff(t.order_date, t.min_order_date, week) = 1 then t.customerId end) as g_1_cust,
             count(distinct case when datediff(t.order_date, t.min_order_date, week) = 2 then t.customerId end) as g_2_cust,
              . . .
  from (Select t.*, Date(orderProcessingTime) as order_date,
               min(date(orderProcessingTime)) over (partition by customerId) as min_order_date
        from UserData.Table_1 t
       ) t
select cohort,
       (G_1_cust * 100.0 / G_0) AS G_1,
       (G_2_cust * 100.0 / G_0) AS G_2,
       . . .
from t
order by 1;
```

You say the original query works fine, so I haven't made other changes.  It is very tempting to summarize the data by week and customer eliminating the `count(distinct)`.

```
      select date_trunc(t.min_order_date, week) as cohort_week,
             count(*) as G_0,
             avg(case when datediff(t.order_date, t.min_order_date, week) = 1 then 100.0 else 0 end) as g_1,
             avg(case when datediff(t.order_date, t.min_order_date, week) = 2 then 100.0 else 0 end) as g_2
              . . .
  from (Select t.customerid, 
               date_trunc(orderProcessingTime, week) as order_date,
               min(date(date_trunc(orderProcessingTime, week))) over (partition by customerId) as cohort_week
        from UserData.Table_1 t
        group by customerId, order_date
       ) t
  order by cohort_week;
```

Comment: Thanks for your insights Gordon. :)